# More efficient way to group mongo documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My documents in mongo are stored this way:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea779501b4757cbca33e8e0"),
        "direction" : 180,
        "latitude" : -3.724404,
        "longitude" : -38.557694,
        "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:34Z"),
        "odometer" : 161245809,
        "routecode" : 0,
        "speed" : 0,
        "deviceid" : 148469,
        "vehicleid" : 33089
}
```

I need to group this documents based on the day that is on the "metrictimestamp" field and count the amount of vehicles that has that same day, i'm using the following query (please notice that is on pymongo):

```
pipe = [

     {
      "$addFields": {
        "date": {

            "$substrBytes": [
              "$metrictimestamp",
              0,
              10
            ]

        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "vehicleid": "$vehicleid",
          "date": "$date"
        },
        "count": {
          "$sum": 1
        }
      }
    }
              ]
```

This works just fine for me, but I can't stop thinking that there's a more efficient way to do this, apreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the date formatting (or conversion) within the `$group` stage, and hence avoid the initial `$addFields` stage. Having additional stages is not good for processing, especially, with large datasets.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      "$group": { 
          "_id": { 
              "vehicleid": "$vehicleid",
              "date": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$metrictimestamp" } } 
          },
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      } 
  }
] )
```